# Add a second /etc/passwd + /etc/shadow + /etc/group combination

Tags: authentication, pam, passwd, shadow

Is it possible to add a second /etc/passwd + /etc/shadow + /etc/group combination like this to a linux system?

```
/etc/passwd
/etc/passwd2
/etc/shadow
/etc/shadow2
/etc/group 
/etc/group2
```

During authentication process PAM should use all of this files.

Background is a **chrooted** application that should add/delete **main system** users and groups via union rw-mounts. But if possible I don't want to merge this two worlds in the main passwd.

Comment: I think you may create a new pam entry and use "pam_listfile" module. I never use it

Answer (score 2):

Since the **pam_unix** uses NSS to access the `passwd`, `shadow` and `group` files, you can use an appropriate NSS module like [libnss-extrausers](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/libnss-extrausers) and modify `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to contain:

```
passwd:         compat extrausers
group:          compat extrausers
shadow:         compat extrausers
```

The **extrausers** module allows you to use a second set of files located at the (hardcoded) location `/var/lib/extrausers`.